# Confusion with prompts and alerts

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var Name = prompt("Enter Your Name");
var Age = prompt("Enter Your Age. This should be an integer.");
if (Age < 12) { 
    alert("Sorry, You must be at least 12 to enter this site!");
    exit }
var Sex = prompt("Enter Your Sex. This should be a single letter input F or M");
if (Sex != "M", "F") {
    alert("Sex must be a single letter F or M");
    }


// -->
</script>
```

Im trying to get only an "M" of "F" from the Sex prompt, but I'm really not sure how to do that. Right now it gets to the end of the code and no matter what I type into the Sex prompt the alert "Sex must be a single letter F or M" pops up. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been stumped for a couple days now.

Comment: `if (Sex != "M", "F")` is incorrect javascript syntax. It could cause some troubles.

Comment: Well, `"M", "F"` is not a valid way to check if it's either of the two. The code you are showing is pretty flawed, maybe try and do a JS introduction first?

Comment: You should probably read up on this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: Suggest going through some basic tutorials and/or a good beginner's book so you're not constantly getting tripped up. Syntax can be tricky. :-)

Comment: @tryzniak Actually, it is valid syntax, that's why it's so hard to debug. The comma operator yields the last value as its result, in this case `"F"`, which is a truthy value, ergo the `if` condition is considered met.

Comment: @máté-safranka wow, today I learned :)

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript and most other similar-looking languages, you have to be fairly verbose when checking against two values:

```
if (Sex != "M" && Sex != "F") {
```

Each part (`Sex != "M"` and `Sex != "F"`) is a complete `!=` expression, and then the overall thing is an `&&` ("and") expression.

There *are* other ways to do it (a `switch`, or a fairly obscure thing like `if (!["M", "F"].includes(Sex))`), but the above is the standard way to do a simple check against two values.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I never thought of that, thank you so much!

Comment: So on the same topic, how would you request specifically an integer from a prompt?

Comment: @JacobRider You can use `parseInt()` to turn the received string into a number: `var age = parseInt(prompt('Enter your age'))`